# Casting an Enumeration with Descriptions into a Dictionary

Tags: c#, reflection, enum

The Enumeration in question is based on `int`, so the following Extension returns a `Dictionary<int, string>` of the Enum's Value and Description.

Is there a cleaner way of implementing this?

```
public enum TeamDepartments
{
    [Description("Geschäftsleitung")] Management = 1,
    [Description("Verkaufsleitung")] Sales = 2
}

public static class UtilityExtensions
{
    public static Dictionary<int, string> ToDictionary(this Type EnumerationType)
    {
        Dictionary<int, string> RetVal = new Dictionary<int,string>();
        var AllItems = Enum.GetValues(EnumerationType);
        foreach (var CurrentItem in AllItems)
        {
            DescriptionAttribute[] DescAttribute = (DescriptionAttribute[])EnumerationType.GetField(CurrentItem.ToString()).GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);
            string Description = DescAttribute.Length > 0 ? DescAttribute[0].Description : CurrentItem.ToString();
            RetVal.Add((int)CurrentItem, Description);
        }
        return RetVal;
    }
}
```

Comment: The method name should be `GetDescription`. Also, the dictionary is unnatural because you lose some of the type-safety, plus you are not wasting THAT much time if you call `GetDescription` every time. If you do want to keep the dictionary anyway, then I would at least wrap access to it into a method with a tighter signature.

Comment: The larger context for this Extension is binding an Enum to an ASP.net dropdown, which now occurs to me can be refactored into a single method.

Comment: I have often dealt with a situation where I need to display something in a combo box, something that does not change very often, something that does not have too many possible values, but also something that comes from a database. My situation is very similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5886394/how-to-keep-a-c-sharp-enum-in-sync-with-a-table-in-database At the end of it I decided that it is better to not use Enums, but have a small object that overrides a `ToString` for display purposes but also contains a bunch of other useful info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have this class in my code which is very similar to what you are looking for:

```
public static class EnumHelper {
    public static string GetRealName(this Enum value) {
        if (value == null) {
            throw new ArgumentException("value");
        }

        string name = value.ToString();
        var fieldInfo = value.GetType().GetField(name);
        if (fieldInfo == null) return "";
        var attributes = (RealNameAttribute[])fieldInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(RealNameAttribute), false);

        if (attributes.Length > 0) {
            name = attributes[0].Name;
        }

        return name;
    }
    public static bool IsIgnored(this Enum value) {
        if (value == null) {
            throw new ArgumentException("value");
        }

        string name = value.ToString();
        var fieldInfo = value.GetType().GetField(name);

        return fieldInfo == null || fieldInfo.IsDefined(typeof(IgnoreAttribute), true);
    }

    public static Dictionary<int, string> ToDictionary(this Type enumType) { 
        return Enum.GetValues(enumType)
            .Cast<object>()
            .Where(f => !((Enum)f).IsIgnored())
            .ToDictionary(k => (int)k, v => ((Enum)v).GetRealName()); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should separate the code returning the attributes of a type into another extension method. It would probably prove useful later on, anyway. Perhaps return an IEnumerable<> of attributes, and process it into a dictionary using a LINQ statement.